# Setting QGIS CRS to UTM Zone 17P

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm looking to set my default project CRS to UTM Zone 17P (for southern Costa Rica) but can't seem to find any epsg codes or files of any kind for this particular projection. I do get 17N, but no 17P.

Comment: Can you link a reference to some site that shows what CRS you actually mean? Here, I can't find any reference to it: https://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=UTM+Zone+17 so it might not exist or under another name? Please make clear what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The "P" is a Latitude Band, between 8° and 16°. EPSG:32617 WGS 84/UTM zone 17N is probably what you're looking for.
[image]

Comment: That's it. 17N it is. Thanks.

Comment: @CA.Archy: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Searching by name should yield you a result, via the CRS section in Project Properties. If you can't find it and you know the parameters, you can add it via Settings > Custom projections.

I do find it unusual, that this projection should not be in the list, when it appears to be actually used around Panama.